# Core Data NSFetchedResultsController one to many for swift titleForHeader

Tags: ios, swift

I have found many examples of this, but none seem to work for my situation.

My data model is this.

I have a one to many relationship of **Project** <->> **Entry**.

**Entry** has an attribute of **category** which is a String.

I want to populate a TableView inside a **Project** that shows all the **entries** for that **Project** organized by the **Entry**.**category** as the titleForHeaderInSection.

```
func allCategoriesFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Project")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"(ANY entries == %@)", self.currentProject)


    return fetchRequest
}
```

And loading the data....

```
func loadInitialData() {

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: allCategoriesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "entries.category", cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
}
```

I get no error, but I get no data either. I am a beginner with iOS and have been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent. Thank you. Just what I was looking for. This is what I tweaked based on ColdLogic's answer. In case it helps someone else.

```
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entry")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "project == %@", self.currentProject)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a lot here.

Your current fetch request says "find any project where its entries are equal to the current project". When what you want to say is "find any entry where its project is equal to the current project".

Lets try to do it using an `NSFetchRequest`.

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entry")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor.sortDescriptorWithKey("name", ascending: true)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "project == %@", self.currentProject)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

The reason your code doesn't error is because its valid code. It will look for all the projects where an entry is equal to the current project, which will be never, because you won't have any projects as entry objects in your entries field of a project. So that is why you are getting no data.

If you don't want to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, and if your model is set such that you have a set of `Entry` objects in the `entries` field of your `Project` object, then you can just do:

```
let entries = self.currentProject.entries
```

to get all your `Entry` objects. This will be a `NSSet` though, so you have to change it into an array to have it sorted

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor.sortDescriptorWithKey("name", ascending: true)
let sortedEntries = entries.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDesriptor])
```

Wrote all this code without testing, so let me know if there is a problem and I will update.

Comment: Perfect, that worked brilliantly. There were a couple of tweaks for my instance. But got the exact results I needed. Thank you ColdLogic.